# [express,mysql]Question using mysql data in non-app.js files

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

https://github.com/kimwoon11/nodejs
I have GitHub. And this is the fourth directory.
Please refer to the link.
The problem is the sing-up.js file in the routes directory.
rendered sign-up.ejs file has a membership form!

```
router.get('/sign-up', function(req, res, next) {res.render('sign-up');});<br>
```

**I'd like to make id duplicate check.**

but, I know that ejs file can't use DOM function.
so, External JavaScript file imported into sign-up.ejs!!

```
<script src="../public/javascripts/idCheck.js"></script><br>
```

but it's not working.

What did I do wrong?

And can we solve this problem in another smarter way?

Comment: You're mixing front end code (`<br><script src="../public/javascripts/idCheck.js"></script><br>`) with backend code (`router.get('/sign-up', function(req, res, next) {res.render('sign-up');});`). How about you add `<script src="../public/javascripts/idCheck.js"></script>` to the bottom of your EJS file?

Comment: @Tyler2P I've already added <script src="../public/javascripts/idCheck.js"></script> to the bottom of my EJS file.

Comment: You are mixing client code, that should run in the browser, with back-end code which should run on the server.
It seems like you're trying to check if the id already exists in the DB. For this you should have a form on the sign-up page, that form would have a action which will post a request to a back-end route which should extract the id from the request body and rerender the sign-up page with eventual errors if is the case.